# Retrieving an address stored as a string

Tags: c, pointers, format

I have a string

```
char value[16]="ffffffffc06e91"
```

and I need to retrieve the address stored as a string in the variable value.

ie..

```
void * ptr = NULL;
somefunction(value,ptr); // ptr = 0xffffffffc06e91
```

Is there such a function or a method to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: with strtouint() in the stdlib, you can convert with base hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `atoi()`; an `int` value probably isn't big enough to store this value, and the function won't work with hexadecimal strings.

Use [`strtoll()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) instead:

```
void *ptr = (void*)strtoll("ffffffffc06e91", NULL, 16);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , figured it out myself too , I'll mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

We could use strtol to accomplish this, thanks to @Bwebb for pointing out atoi which led me to strtol.

```
void * ptr = (void*)(long)strtol(value,NULL,16);
```

Comment: This is wrong, you should use strtoll and you should not cast to long which probably only are 4 bytes long.